# How to read a file, included in the package, in Netbeans

Tags: java, file, netbeans

I am having difficulty reading a file that I included in a package I am working on for school. The files I need to read, "InputFile1.txt" and InputFile2.txt" are located in a folder called "Lab Exercise 3 Input" in the "Source Packages" folder.

Here is my code for this part:

```
// create necessary variables

    private static ArrayList<String> inputArrayOne = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList<String> inputArrayTwo = new ArrayList();
    private static String nextLine;
    private static int currentIndex = 0;
    private static int n;
    private static int swapCount = 0;
    private static String string1;
    private static String string2;


    /**
     * Main method to run
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            // assign the files to be read
            File inputOne = new File("Lab Exercise 3 Input/InputFile1.txt");
            File inputTwo = new File("Lab Exercise 3 Input/InputFile2.txt");

            // create a scanner objects to read the files
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputOne);
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(inputTwo);

            // while loop to iterate through the first file
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){

                // assign the next line of the file to a string
                nextLine = sc.nextLine();

                // add that string to an array
                inputArrayOne.add(nextLine);

            } // end while loop

            // close the first scanner
            sc.close();
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried changing the filename to "InputFile1.txt" without any change. This assignment is due tonight 10/27/17 at 11:59 pm, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you miss `/` ?

Comment: What errors are you getting? You might want to try using absolute paths to the input files if there are problems opening them.

Comment: We are required to read the file from the package. The error message is as follows:                                                                                           Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Lab Exercise 3 Input\InputFile1.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss `/` .

```
File inputOne = new File("/Lab Exercise 3 Input/InputFile1.txt");
File inputTwo = new File("/Lab Exercise 3 Input/InputFile2.txt");
```

You should put your main method in class as well.

```
public class Example
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      }
}
```

Comment: It is located in a class, I accidentally didn't copy that part when posting. The added "/" did not change my error

Comment: where you stored it ? Post the full path and also the error you get

Comment: this is what comes up when I print (dir + /Lab Exercise 3 Input/InputFile1.txt") "C:\Users\Shannon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Meadows_Robert_Lab03/Lab Exercise 3 Input/InputFile1.txt                                                              the error is Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Shannon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Meadows_Robert_Lab03\Lab Exercise 3 Input\InputFile1.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: You need to have full path, which include `C:/`. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841690/5156075

Comment: C:\Users\Shannon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Meadows_Robert_Lab03\src\Lab Exercise 3 Input\InputFile1.txt

Comment: Yes..Check the link I sent to you

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the current directory and adding that to the File location

```
String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File inputOne = new File(dir + "\\Lab Exercise 3 Input\\InputFile1.txt");
```

**Edit:**

I put a file named `InputFile1.txt` into a folder named `Lab Exercise 3 Input` into the `Source Packages` folder

Then put together a quick bit of code and it worked as expected:

```
String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
ArrayList<String> inputArrayOne = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(dir + "\\Lab Exercise 3 Input\\InputFile1.txt"));
while (sc.hasNext()) {
      inputArrayOne.add(sc.nextLine());
}
```

My only other thought is you saved the file as `InputFile1.txt` but it's also saved as a `.txt` file, and therefore is actually

```
InputFile1.txt.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. However, I add /src/ onto the rest of the filename and it did work. I have since then discovered that the files can be stored in the folder with all of the package information, than be accessed using only the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Java knows the concept of **resource**, a "file" on the class path, together with the .class files, and possible packed in a single application .jar. Hence the path uses slashes (`/`) and is case-sensitive. Also `File` cannot be used, as te resource might be packed in a jar. And of course a resource is read-only.

```
        InputStream inputOne = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/Lab Exercise 3 Input/InputFile1.txt");
        InputStream inputTwo = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/Lab Exercise 3 Input/InputFile2.txt");

        // create a scanner objects to read the files
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputOne);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(inputTwo);
```

There also is a Scanner constructor with charset, so you could tell that the file is for instance in "UTF-8".